# Scanning multiple CSV files to append a single output file

Tags: csv, vbscript

Starting with this as the code:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForAppending = 8

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objSourceFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Path\file.csv", ForReading)

Set objDestinationFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Path\Database.csv", ForAppending)

'Loop start files in dir
Do Until objSourceFile.AtEndOfStream

    strLine = objSourceFile.ReadLine

    arrFields = Split(strLine, ",")

    If arrFields(0) <> """""" Then
        strContents = strContents & arrFields(1) & ","  
    End If

Loop
strContents = strContents & vbCrLf
objSourceFile.Close
objDestinationFile.Write strContents
'Move source file to processed directory
'Loop end files in dir


objDestinationFile.Close
```

Which is fine for one file at a time, but I'm trying to append many files into the single file.

Appreciate any tips.

Thanks.

Edit: So this was a request that started with a single file which turned into having to migrate many files. The original CSV needed to have its format changed and then placed into another easier to use CSV. 
The issue is that there many files and each source file has to be modified before placing it into the destination file. I am new to VB Scripting and I was trying to be concise with my text. Thanks.
I appreciate the help.

Comment: Then what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Tip: do not collect file contents into a string - if you want it in a file, write it to that file. (As much as I'm in favour of commenting code, I cant find the equivalent of `'Loop start files in dir`)

Comment: Time allowing, peruse [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). (Welcome to Stack Overflow!)